# Pandoc template: How to slice an YAML array by index?

Tags: yaml, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to make a custom pandoc template. It should read an array from the YAML data but only display certain items based on their indices. The pandoc user guide says I can use `first` and `last` to return the first and last values of an array. Is there a way to get the value of other indices?

My YAML and template file are as follows, and I'd like the output to only show Item2 and Item3.

**YAML**

```
Array:
  - Item1
  - Item2
  - Item3
  - Item4
  - Item5

Indices: [2, 3]
```

**Template**

```
$for(Indices)$
  $Array$[$Indices$]
$endfor$
```

**Current Output**

```
Item1Item2Item3Item4Item5[2] 
Item1Item2Item3Item4Item5[3]
```

**Desired Output**

```
Item2
Item3
```

Comment: Welcome! Please detail what is wrong, "not working" is too general. And also check you code posted here, there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added detail about the output and corrected the typo.